# I need to pass data from table to post handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I need help. I`m new at razor pages and asp.net core and I need to send the data that I have in HTML table to my post handler a save it.

I reorder rows on client and then I need save reordered rows on button click.

```
<form method="post">
    <div>

        <table id="example" class="table table-stripped border">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DenniPlan.FirstOrDefault().CisloZakazky)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DenniPlan.FirstOrDefault().CisloProduktu)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DenniPlan.FirstOrDefault().Poradi)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.DenniPlan)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CisloZakazky)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CisloProduktu)</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Poradi)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Časovat</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
    private readonly DataContext _context;
    public IEnumerable<DenniPlan2> DenniPlan { get; set; }      

    public IndexModel(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        DenniPlan = await _context.DenniPlan2.Take(20).OrderBy(x => x.Poradi).ToListAsync();

    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason you use `DisplayFor` and need to submit without changing anything in `DenniPlan`?

Answer (score 1):

For submitting data, you need to render data with `input`. Otherwise, you need to use jquery to loop the `td` node. But, IMO, it is unreasonable to submit data without changing anything.

1. IndexPage

   ```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly TestRazor.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

       public IndexModel(TestRazor.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }
       [BindProperty]
       public IList<DenniPlan2> DenniPlan2 { get;set; }

       public async Task OnGetAsync()
       {
           DenniPlan2 = await _context.DenniPlan2s.Take(3).ToListAsync();
       }
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
       {
           var r = DenniPlan2;

           return RedirectToPage("./Index");
       }

   }
   ```
2. View

   ```
   <form method="post">
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[0].CisloZakazky)
                   </th>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[0].CisloProduktu)
                   </th>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[0].Poradi)
                   </th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DenniPlan2.Count; i++)
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[i].CisloZakazky)
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[i].CisloProduktu)
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DenniPlan2[i].Poradi)
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
   ```